# Screwing off Showerhead

Tags: shower

I've been trying to unscrew off this showerhead. I've tried two things but neither have worked. I just want to check with the DIY community before I break something drastic.

1. [Red area] I've twisted this area counterclockwise but I don't think it has had any effect. I think it's just a ball and socket that allows the showerhead to be aimed.
2. [Blue area] I've also tried to rotate this part but it doesn't turn. I suspect I may need to get a wrench to do it.

My question is are there any other possible ways to remove that showerhead or is #2 the most likely course of action?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the connection because it has a wrap of PTFE (Teflon) tape (just above the blue section). Someone used a pliers on it and boogered it up, but there are flats for an open-end or adjustable wrench. You can see one of them on the lower edge facing the photographer.

Support the pipe nipple as you turn the fitting--don't crank on it or you might damage the nipple or the plumbing in the wall.